# How do you get a request variable using the python albatross framework

Tags: python, apache, mod-python

I have inherited a python project, and I admit that I am a noob on this, but the project is done using the albatross framework. I have added two fields to a form: "password" and "random". I now need to know how to retrieve those form fields on the back end. In php it would be the following:

```
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$random = $_REQUEST['random'];
```

I have been searching for information about how to do this, using the albatross framework, and have had trouble finding anything that works in the platform I have inherited. This is in apache 2.6, using mod_python, and relying on the RequestFields functionality in albatross.cgiapp.

Does anybody know how to do this, quick-and-dirty, or via a decent tutorial, that is specific to the framework that I am using? The albatross documentation doesn't seem to tell how to get data from form fields, and digging through the source code doesn't seem to be turning up much.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the section on [using forms](http://www.object-craft.com.au/projects/albatross/albatross/tempuser.html#using-forms-to-receive-user-input) in the manual? This explains things pretty well.

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

Now `form` should contain a dictionary with all your form data.

Comment: I've tried, but I get an exception "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'".

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed that you were using `mod_python`. CGI features won't work with `mod_python`.